# how to install initctl on a centos-7 box

Tags: centos, centos7, init

```
service autofs restart
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service autofs restart
/etc/init.d/autofs: line 54: initctl: command not found
```

I have looked up on the web and do not see any yum package that can install initctl. can you please help.

Answer (score 4):

CentOS 7 comes with **systemctl** to manage service. You don't need to use initctl.

`service autofs restart` should point to `systemctl restart autofs`

You can check the status of this service with `systemctl status autofs` and post us the output if not able to restart.